# how to add another collection data with in a doc id in firebase using express node js

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add another collection of data with in a doc id in firebase below is the database path for referance.

```
screams/(doc_id)/(users)
```

please find the below api post call to add the data.

```
 app.post('/screams/:id',(req,res)=>{
   const mark ={
       Mark:req.body.Mark,
       Name:req.body.Name
   }
    db.collection('screams').doc(req.params.id).doc('users').add(mark)
    .then(doc=>{
        return res.status(200).json({handle: 'data added successfully'})
    })
})
```

when i tried to add the data its giving me an error

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).doc(...).add is not a function
    at app.post (/srv/index.js:141:49)
```

please help me to sort out the issue. 
if you can also suggest me a way to get the added data would be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`add()` is a method of a [`CollectionReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference), but with

```
db.collection('screams').doc(req.params.id).doc('users')
```

you are not defining a `CollectionReference`, since you call twice the `doc()` method.

---

You need to call the [`collection()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#collection) method of the [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) defined by `db.collection('screams').doc(req.params.id)`, as follows:

```
app.post('/screams/:id',(req,res) => {
   const mark ={
       Mark:req.body.Mark,
       Name:req.body.Name
   }
    db.collection('screams').doc(req.params.id).collection('users').add(mark)
    .then(docRef => {
        return res.status(200).json({handle: 'data added successfully'})
    })
})
```

Comment: thanks it worked :) . Also can u please suggest me an option to get all the data in the collection 'screams' (including users collection) or just suggest me an option to get only users collection data please